# search of consecutive equal numbers in a list and add them to a new list - using pure python

Tags: python, list

I need to accomplish this task without any external libraries, without `any`, `map` or `zip`. For example:

```
lst = [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,1,1]

repeated_num = [1,2,2,3,1]
```

my code so far:

```
lst = input().split(',')
repeated_num = []
for i in range(len(lst)-1):
    if lst[i] == lst[i+1]:
         repeated_num.append(lst[i])
        
repeated_num
```

as you might see, this only works for 2 consecutive equal numbers. so a `[2,2,2]` would give `[2,2]`, not good.

Comment: Is this a school assignment? What kind of school doesn't let you used the standard library?

Comment: @DaniMesejo it is, they do this to make it harder on us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Dominic inspired me, thanks!

```
repeated_num = []
lst = input().split(',')

for i in range(len(lst)):
    lst[i] = int(lst[i])

sizeoflist = len(lst)

currentnumber = 0
for i in range(sizeoflist - 1):
    if lst[i] == lst[i + 1]:
        if currentnumber == 0:
            currentnumber = 1
            repeated_num.append(lst[i])
    else:
        currentnumber = 0

print(repeated_num)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this (elements are added if it is equal to the next element `and` (it isn't the last element in the list containing repeats `or` it is different to the previous element)):

```
repeated = []
for i, j in enumerate(lst[:-1], 1):
    if j == lst[i] and (repeated[-1:] != [j] or j != lst[i-2]):
        repeated.append(j)
```

Output (with given input):

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 1]
```

Or in Python 3.8+ you can use the `:=` operator and do it in a list comprehension:

```
n = None
[n:=j for i, j in enumerate(lst[:-1], 1) if j == lst[i] and (n != j or j != lst[i-2])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a couple extra variables, you can keep track of the last number to appear, and how many times it has appeared in succession.

```
lst = [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,1,1]
repeated_num = []
last = lst[0]
count = 1
for x in lst[1:]:
    if x == last:
        count += 1
        if count == 2:
            repeated_num.append(last)
    else:
        last = x
        count = 1
print(repeated_num)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 1]
```

Comment: looping over a range for getting items from the list is unpythonic; loop over the list instead.

Comment: True, fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

```py
repeated_num = [[lst[0],1]]
for i in lst[1:]:
    if i == repeated_num[-1][0]:
        repeated_num[-1][1] += 1
    else:
        repeated_num.append([i,1])
# strip and filter counts
repeated_num = [i[0] for i in repeated_num if i[1] > 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach using while instead of for, since for this case (in my opinion) it let's you handle iteration better:

```
lst = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

res = []
length, index = len(lst), 0

while index < length:
    last = lst[index]

    # while the current value is equal to the last iterate
    run_length = 0
    while index + run_length < length and lst[index + run_length] == last:
        run_length += 1

    #  if the run of consecutive values was greater than 1 append to result
    if run_length > 1:
        res.append(last)

    # move index forward
    index += run_length

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 1]
```

The idea is to increase the counter while there is run of consecutive numbers, then check if the run of consecutive numbers is larger than 1, if positive add on representative to the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
lst = [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,1,1]

repeated_numbers = []
counter = 0
for x in range(len(lst)-1):
    if repeated_numbers != [] and repeated_numbers[-1] != lst[x]:
        counter =0

    if counter == 0 and lst[x] == lst[x+1]:
        repeated_numbers.append(lst[x])
        counter +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner without `:=`:

```py
lst = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

out = [
    lst[i]
    for i in range(1, len(lst))
    if lst[i - 1] == lst[i] and (i == 1 or lst[i - 2] != lst[i - 1])
]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[1, 2, 2, 3, 1]
```